# OpenCv Python function called multiple times does not write files to user specified directory after initial call

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv

In my new role I've been getting back into Python after many years away so if there's something I miss bear with me here. I have a Python script which controls a lab test stand and runs a threaded function which uses the OpenCv module to save video from an external webcam. This function is called multiple times throughout the script. The only argument that gets passed to the function is a filename which is updated before the next function call. I'm trying to add a feature where the generated video files get saved to a user specified directory.

The function in question:

```
def video_capture(filename):
    #  @staticmethod
        
    # text to display on recorded video
    in_line_text = filename

    # Capture video from webcam
    #vid_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # 0 = webcam, 1 = usb webcam
    vid_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW) #captureDevice = camera

    #set font type
    font_face = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    # Set the camera resolution to (800 x 600)
    vid_capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 800)
    vid_capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 600)
    time.sleep(0.1)

    # Set the frame rate to 30 fps
    vid_capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 20.0)
    time.sleep(0.1)

    vid_cod = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    output = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, vid_cod, 20.0, (800, 600))
    startvid = time.time()

    while(True):
        #  Capture each frame of webcam video
        ret, frame = vid_capture.read()
        
                
        #Use putText() method for inserting text on video
        cv2.putText(frame, in_line_text, (50,50), font_face, 1, (0, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_4)
        
        #display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow(in_line_text, frame)
     
        output.write(frame)
        if time.time() - startvid > 35:  # Recording stops when timer > 35 sec
            break
        # Close and break the loop after pressing "x" key
        if cv2.waitKey(1) &0XFF == ord('x'):
            break

    # close the already opened camera
    vid_capture.release()
    # close the already opened file
    output.release()
    # close the window and de-allocate any associated memory usage
    # Added in the cv2.waitKey(0) statment before and after the
    # cv2.destroyAllWindows() statement
    cv2.waitKey(5000)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Here is an example of the code block that is used to initiate the threaded function:

```
# start video capture thread
    filename = partial_filename + ';' + time_point + ';' + action + ';blah blah blah.mp4'
    t = threading.Thread(target=video_capture, args=[filename])
    t.start()
```

`partial_filename` is a string pulled from a user input and `time_point` as well as `action` are strings that get updated as the script progresses.

Currently, the script saves the files to the same directory the function is stored in, and the user has to manually move the files to their desired directory in file explorer once the test is complete. In its current state, the script has no problem with saving the files correctly. However, when I add the code to change the working directory to the user specified directory, the called function will only save the initial video file correctly. All subsequently generated files are empty.

Initially I thought it might be an issue of the webcam not playing well with the code but the problem persists when I try a different webcam. I have tried using `os.path.join()` and am currently using `os.chdir()` to change the working directory. Neither has resolved the issue. When I added a print statement to check the status of ret after `ret, frame = vid_capture.read()`, in subsequent calls of the function after the intial call, the statement would only print once. The user specified path is pulled as a string from a user input in a GUI for what its worth. Happy to provide more information if needed. It's likely that I am missing something blatantly obvious as a result of my inexperience but hopefully that's not the case.